# array containing objects to single object containing said objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I'm currently getting all the data from a firebase firestore collection in this format :

```
[
 {
  id: GEU8E3UJSSB33749K,
  advancedPayments: 20,
  ...
 },
 {
  id: FETB73UJSSBREF59V,
  advancedPayments: 20,
  },
  ...
]
```

To be able to better access this data with Redux i need to convert it to this format :

```
{
 GEU8E3UJSSB33749K: {
  advancedPayments: 20,
  ...
 },
 FETB73UJSSBREF59V: {
  advancedPayments: 20,
 },
 ...
}
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Your desired format is not valid javascript syntax. Object literals contain key-value pairs.

Comment: @Yousaf Thank you... I made a mistake earlier I've made the changes to a proper object

Comment: @sascha Thank you also... I made a mistake earlier I've made the changes to a proper object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate your data. Iterating over your objects create in the accumulated object a propetry for the id and add th whole object to it. Delete after this the id from it.
**Note:** I add the whole object and delete the id-property instead to iterate over all properties and check if the key is unequal to id and add only these to th new object because this should be faster (especially if you have much miore properties).

```js
let arr = [
 {
  id: 'GEU8E3UJSSB33749K',
  advancedPayments: 20,
 },
 {
  id: 'FETB73UJSSBREF59V',
  advancedPayments: 20,
  }
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.id] = cur;
    delete acc[cur.id].id;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
   let res = [
     {
      id: 'GEU8E3UJSSB33749K',
      advancedPayments: 20,
     },
     {
      id: 'FETB73UJSSBREF59V',
      advancedPayments: 20,
      }
    ].reduce((accumulator, obj) => {
        const {advancedPayments} = obj;
        return {
          ...accumulator,
          [obj.id]: { advancedPayments }
        };
    }, {});

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: This works only because your objects has only `id` and `advancedPayments` but there are more properties OP has `...`.